# Force specific selection of option combobox

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 and have the following. How do I change the code so that whenever a radio button is changed - of the options in the combobox "world" will always become the visible option - if the graphic was showing anything other than world it should change to world ?

Data:

```
Category,country
XXX,mex
XXX,world
XXX,mex
XXX,ireland
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,world
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,usa
ZZZ,aruba
ZZZ,ireland
YYY,foo
YYY,world
YYY,foo
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>comboBoxWithRadios</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    #projection-menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 45px;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="radioDiv">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="XXX"> XXX</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="YYY" checked> YYY</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="ZZZ">ZZZ</label>
    </div>
    <select id="projection-menu"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.select("input[value=\"YYY\"]").property("checked", true);
    var exampleCSV = "comboBoxWithRadios.csv"


    selectDataset();

    d3.selectAll("input")
        .on("change", selectDataset);

    function selectDataset() {

        var v = this.value;
        if (undefined == v) {
            v = "YYY"
        }

        d3.csv(exampleCSV, function(rows) {
            dta = rows.filter(function(row) {
                if (row['Category'] == v) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            //clear out the combobox
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("projection-menu"));

            var menu = d3.select("#projection-menu")
                .on("change", change);
            console.log(d3.map(dta, function(d){return d.country;}))
            menu.selectAll("option")
                .data(d3.map(dta, function(d){return d.country;}).keys())
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
                });
        });
    };


    function removeOptions(selectbox) {
        var i;
        for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectbox.remove(i);
        }
    }

    function change() {
        console.log(this.value);
    };


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.property("selected", function(d){ 
    return d === "world"; 
})
```

In your code, it should be this:

```
menu.selectAll("option")
    .data(d3.map(dta, function(d) {
        return d.country;
    }).keys())
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .property("selected", function(d) {
        return d === "world";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Here is your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PRkGX2zvTBmftoGwvHnr?p=preview

PS: your CSV file is wrong in your plunker.

Comment: thanks for help Gerardo - I've changed my link to a different plunk that has the title function in it: I must have forgot to save the previous plunk

Comment: I've added your additional code and it definitely fixes things in relation to original partial plunk I linked to, but now if you select a country say "usa" so the text says "usa" > then hit a radio > the text in the combo is "world" but the title still shows "usa"

Comment: Well, I answered your *specific* question, just dealing with the drop down menu. I didn't even see this title. What you're asking now is *another* question and, as you know, it should be in a new post.

Comment: I know totally my fault - the plunk and the code in the original question were not consistent - title was in the code in the original question.

Comment: This issue is solved. Please post *another* question with the new problem.

Comment: Apologies Gerardo (....everyone seems to be moody today - maybe a world-wide thing!) ....I always up your answers and mark them correct.

Comment: I'm fine, I'm not moody! I'm just trying to avoid a chain of questions. In S.O. I have a policy, "one question per post". Sometimes the OP makes a question, we provide the answer, and then he/she replies "but now something else is not working", we fix the something else, and then a new something else shows up... do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: for the lesser known language tag `mdx` I'm on top in terms of answers (although I'm only here to learn) - so I completely understand what you mean by "..one more thing please..." -  but in the case of the question above if you go to the very first draft you will notice the inconsistency between the code embedded in my question and my plunk - I genuinely forgot to save the plunk: the title code is in the embedded code and also in my explanation. Here is the follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020467/why-does-this-title-graphic-not-update-with-world

Comment: No worries. Feel free to delete the new question, I just answered it (see the second plunkr in my answer and two comments above).

Comment: ...I've written it now! and also I've amended above so it is just the initial issue... just add a link to that plunk as the answer and I will mark it the answer!